# Eventbridge integrations with shopify

Tags: shopify, integration, aws-event-bridge

I am trying integrate eventbridge with shopify but I can't understand what went wrong and not getting any responses to my target clouwatch log. I added eventbridge to my shopify app and a bus was created and I added a rule to trigger the event for product on cloudwatch log. Nothing happens, can anyone help here?

Comment: Did you add the webhook?

Comment: No, I tried to do it with aws service partner service which allows to use eventbridge services without webhooks I guess but now doing it with webhooks.

Comment: No you still need a webhook. But instead of the http endpoint you put the ARN

Comment: Yes, I am doing it that way right now. I tried to use it without a webhook but I think there are some issues I faced with eventpattern.

Answer (score -1):

General setup for eventbridge:

1. Set up an event source as an so called App
2. Subscribe the event source app to a webhook vie Admin API

https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/eventbridge

Make sure to use the **App Admin Api Token** from your App when subscribing it via API. Otherwise you will run into this error:

[Attempting to subscribe to a Shopify Webhook w/AWS EventBridge produces error: "Address is an AWS ARN and includes api_client_id 'x' instead of 'y'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523482/attempting-to-subscribe-to-a-shopify-webhook-w-aws-eventbridge-produces-error)

Comment: cru, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)