# Attempting to subscribe to a Shopify Webhook w/AWS EventBridge produces error: "Address is an AWS ARN and includes api_client_id 'x' instead of 'y'"

Tags: shopify, aws-event-bridge

I'm running this request through Postman. Some posts to the Shopify developer forum (e.g., [this one](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/eventbridge-integration-is-broken/m-p/878112#M56034)) express without clear explanation that the request should be made within the Shopify app that would be subscribing to the Webhooks, but Postman seems to work, too.

In Postman . . .

Here's the endpoint:

`https://{{shopifyDevelopmentStoreName}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-07/graphql.json`

Here's the GraphQL body:

```
mutation createWebhookSubscription($topic: WebhookSubscriptionTopic!, $webhookSubscription: EventBridgeWebhookSubscriptionInput!) {
  eventBridgeWebhookSubscriptionCreate(
    topic: $topic,
    webhookSubscription: $webhookSubscription
  ) {
    webhookSubscription {
      id
    }
    userErrors {
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the payload being sent (notice the "client_id_x" value within the `arn` property):

```
{
  "topic": "PRODUCTS_CREATE",
  "webhookSubscription": {
    "arn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1::event-source/aws.partner/shopify.com/client_id_x/LovecraftEventBridgeSource",
    "format": "JSON",
    "includeFields": "id"
  }
}
```

Here's the response I receive:

```
{
    "data": {
        "eventBridgeWebhookSubscriptionCreate": {
            "webhookSubscription": null,
            "userErrors": [
                {
                    "message": "Address is invalid"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Address is an AWS ARN and includes api_client_id 'client_id_x' instead of 'client_id_y'"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "cost": {
            "requestedQueryCost": 10,
            "actualQueryCost": 10,
            "throttleStatus": {
                "maximumAvailable": 1000.0,
                "currentlyAvailable": 990,
                "restoreRate": 50.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's entirely unclear is why Shopify is insisting upon validity of "client_id_y" when, in AWS, the value being displayed is undeniably 'client_id_x'. Extremely confusing. I don't even see what difference using the Shopify app would make except that it produces a `client_id` value that works counter to one's expectations and intuitions.

Does anyone know why the heck Shopify isn't just using the `client_id` value of the event bus created earlier in Amazon EventBridge?

Answer (score 0):

Same happend to me and I was lucky to find a solution.

The error message is just missleading.

I **replaced** the API Access Token for the Shopify Rest API Request (**X-Shopify-Access-Token**)
with the one from the Shopify App holding the aws credentials.

**admin/settings/apps/development -> app -> API credentials -> Admin API access token.** (can only be seen after creation)

Then I could subscribe webhooks to the app via the Rest Interface.

Comment: Sorry but how do you open the REST interface?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. With how you mean what tool? - > With a REST Client, e.g. Postman.

Or how the Rest Api works? -> https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/webhook

Or how to get access? -> https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was not easy. I have been successful with the following procedure:

1. Create a "intern/local" app: Settings > Apps > Add App (a button top right) > Create a new app
2. In the app: Go to Configuration > Admin-API-Integration > Configuration > Add the necessary rights (like read orders) and in the bottom: Add the Amazon EventBus Connection. (My mistake was, that I build a app in the Partner Portal, but such "intern" app is more than necessary.)
3. Than create in the same app under "API-Configuration" a new accessToken
4. With this, you can call the API to create the webhook.

All other parts are nicely covered in the official documentation:
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/webhooks/configuration/eventbridge

Some other resources:

- https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/webhook
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1Yyzq6hAuY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZhd1Y18oWw